# Can a column name in an R dataframe be blank?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm creating a dataframe in R using the following code

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

d <- c('GDP Response to Positive','','CPI Response to Positive','')
s <- c('AS Shock','AD Shock','AS Shock','AD Shock')
sr <- c('+','+','-','+')
lr <- c('+','Neutral','-','+')

data.frame(d,s,sr,lr) %>% 
  rename(``=d)
```

However, when I try to run the `rename` line within my code, I get the following error

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Which I assume means that a column name in a dataframe cannot be blank. Wondering if there are any work-arounds to this? I want the column name to be blank because I'm using this dataframe to create a table using `kableExtra` and I'd like the column name in my table to be blank

Comment: Thanks @IanCampbell, I figured out a workaround to my question so I'll just post it on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `setNames` + `replace` like below

```
df <- data.frame(d, s, sr, lr)
setNames(df, replace(names(df), names(df) == "d", ""))
```

which gives

```
                                  s sr      lr
1 GDP Response to Positive AS Shock  +       +
2                          AD Shock  + Neutral
3 CPI Response to Positive AS Shock  -       -
4                          AD Shock  +       +
```

Answer (score 3):

Just using base R you could use

```
d <- c('GDP Response to Positive','','CPI Response to Positive','')
s <- c('AS Shock','AD Shock','AS Shock','AD Shock')
sr <- c('+','+','-','+')
lr <- c('+','Neutral','-','+')
    
df <- data.frame(d,s,sr,lr)
colnames(df)[1] <-""
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to reassign the column 'd' to `""`, wrap the `""`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(d, s, sr, lr) %>%
       rename(`''` = d)
```

These are non-standard column name, so it would be referenced each time by backquotes

---

The error in the OP's code is not specific to `rename`.  It can be reproduced as with printing just backquotes on the console

```
``
```

> Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name

According to `?colnames`

> For a data frame, value for rownames should be a character vector of non-duplicated and non-missing names (this is enforced), and for colnames a character vector of (preferably) unique syntactically-valid names. In both cases, value will be coerced by as.character, and setting colnames will convert the row names to character.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that it is not possible to create a blank name for a column in an R dataframe, however I only needed the column name to be blank in the actual table that I was creating from the dataframe. So I did the following

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

sr <- c('+','+','-','+')
lr <- c('+','Neutral','-','+')
d <- c('GDP Response to Positive','','CPI Response to Positive','')
s <- c('AS Shock','AD Shock','AS Shock','AD Shock')

data.frame(d,s,sr,lr) %>% 
  kable(col.names = c('','','Short Run','Long Run'))
```

and now the first two columns in my table have blank names